# Gridlines doesn't show in topview anymore (np 7) in Blender 2.8 (Mac)?

Tags: edit-mode

How do I get gridlines shown in topview (np 7) in latest blender 2.8 for mac? I downloaded a new update and after I cant se the gridlines in topview anymore, what to do? I would be happy to be able to editing by this grids after subdivide objekt

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you didn't disable them? Check your Viewport Overlays settings, top right corner of 3D view.

[image]

Comment: Yes, Grid is checked but doesn't show anyway. Im new here and doesn't know how to add pics on the screen to the comments